# Google Apps Script - use query to combine 2 sheets but fail to get the complete

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, string-formatting, number-formatting, google-query-language

I wonder if there's a limitation of number of rows when use query function to combine sheets, and how can we fix it?

**Background**

I have 2 sheets that contain data, Sheet1 and Sheet2. In Sheet1, I have around 13k rows with Date and ID:
[image: Sheet1]

In Sheet2 I have around 4.5k rows and I extract the date from timestamp in column C to make the date value align with Sheet1:

[image: Sheet2]

**Purpose**

I would like to combine Sheet1 and Sheet2 in Sheet3, using unique to deduplicate those rows with the same ID and same Date at the same time.

**Question**

Currently in Sheet3 I use this formula:

[image]

and the dates in Sheet2 somehow don't show up. But when I eliminate most of rows in Sheet1 and, for example, only retain 10 rows, the error in Sheet3 seems to be fixed accordingly.

Can someone help with this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you willing to use Google Apps Script as the title says?

Comment: @Emel Thanks for the input. Sure, but I'm kind of concerned as I already have some script currently functioning, not sure if a conflict would be caused. Thanks!

Comment: @ Emel Here's a briefing for the script: Basically, the existing script fills current timestamp in column D in Sheet3 with onOpen trigger. As my raw data is automatically generated in Sheet1 & Sheet2, I'm trying to label the timestamp for every new row when I open the spreadsheet in order to differentiate the data based on time interval.

Comment: Can you share a sanitized copy of the sheet/script? I'm having a hard time figuring out what the full interactions are between your data.

Comment: @Emel Here's the link Thank you. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bxBFaRARuCYoN460ejhjuHXGaIbvPfGXJNGJeOgG8eM/edit#gid=267282654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(QUERY(UNIQUE(
 {Sheet1!A:A&"×"&Sheet1!B:B; Sheet2!A2:A&"×"&Sheet2!B2:B}), 
 "where Col1 is not null"), "×"), "order by Col2"))
```

#### [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eBxgfTO2cjc1L5Md2GhukEUyhHSe8pYVZbHyTUNKFlo/edit#gid=235097712)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. That formula is dope.